# How to define a list <dataType> with each element is gotten from another list <ObjectType> in JAVA

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have an object OrderDatails, it includes Integer orderId, Integer productId.
From this object, I have a list like: `List<OrderDatails> listOrderDetails`

What I want is create another list to contain orderId, datatype Integer - something like: `List<Integer> listOrderId`, so elements of this list are gotten all orderId in listOrderDetails

How to do that please?

Comment: `List<Integer> listOrderId = listOrderDetails.stream().map(OrderDatails::orderId).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, #YCF_L. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java stream collect function.

```
  List<Integer> listOrderId = listOrderDetails.stream()
            .map(OrderDatails::getListOrderId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to use some libraries for this, I recommended MapStruct  https://mapstruct.org/

Comment: Thanks for you answer, #MacDaddy I can handle it know!